# insert many .txt files (daily) to sql server 2008 table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to import .txt files daily into sql server 2008 table and I want to automate it

so in steps:
 
1- I receive 2 files daily with name hazem.log.date and hazem.log.date2 
2- I need to have a way to import them daily and automatically 
3- I will use the job, but which command or query should be used in this case?

Comment: You can try SQL Jobs

Comment: I doubt that pure sql can read files in general.

Comment: Sql jobs are ok for automating it .. what query should I use to import any files in the folder daily and at once?

Comment: Too broad... What exactly you got a problem with? Be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try running below through SQLServer jobs..

```
BULK INSERT dbo.ImportTest 
FROM 'C:\ImportData.txt' --replace name of your files
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR =',', FIRSTROW = 2 )
```

you also can use

```
bcp dbo.ImportTest in 'C:\ImportData.txt' -T -SserverName\instanceName
```

For Mutiple files..you can do like this..

1.Create a stored proc first..

```
Create procedure usp_ImportMultipleFilesBCP @servername varchar(128),
@DatabaseName varchar(128), @filepath varchar(500), @pattern varchar(100), 
@TableName varchar(128)
as
declare @query varchar(1000)
declare @max1 int
declare @count1 int
Declare @filename varchar(100)
set @count1 =0
create table #x (name varchar(200))
set @query ='master.dbo.xp_cmdshell "dir '+@filepath+@pattern +' /b"'
insert #x exec (@query)
delete from #x where name is NULL
select identity(int,1,1) as ID, name into #y from #x 
drop table #x
set @max1 = (select max(ID) from #y)
--print @max1
--print @count1
--select * from #y
While @count1 <= @max1
begin
set @count1=@count1+1
set @filename = (select name from #y where [id] = @count1)
set @Query ='bcp "'+ @databasename+'.dbo.'+@Tablename + '" 
    in "'+ @Filepath+@Filename+'" -S' + @servername + ' -T -c -r\n -t,'
set @Query = 'MASTER.DBO.xp_cmdshell '+ "'"+  @query +"'"
--print @query
EXEC ( @query)
insert into logtable (query) select @query
end
```

2.Now run above sp to import all files of desired extension

```
Exec usp_ImportMultipleFilesBCP 'SQL','Bank','c:\Myimport\','*.csv','Account'--table account
```

Note:
 You will need to enable [Xp_cmdshell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx)

References:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1207/different-options-for-importing-data-into-sql-server/
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3325701/Import-multiple-Files-to-SQL-Server-using-T-SQL.htm

Comment: This is ok for one file .. but what if they are 10 and I want to import them at once?

Comment: @Zomzomzom:see udpated

Comment: which variables should be changed then is this long query?

Comment: `c:` is your directory,you should create a table with desired name and replace `account`

Comment: Refer to database journal link i have mentioned